# How to draw a polygon given a distance and bearing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I want to draw a polygon given a length and a bearing, basically a square with length 1m. I can't seem to manage it with the existing tools in QGIS 2.4 (I possibly need a plugin).

Comment: This is one of the biggest features from ArcDesktop that I miss.  All those functions when you right click as your creating / editing features are so convenient.  Point at the end of a line is another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a starting point, bearings and distances the Azimuth and Distance plug-in will do this too.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You do not need a plugin for this.

The "Advanced Digitizing Panel" allows for entering distances and angles relative to the currently drawn path or relative to other objects on the map canvas.

[image]

There are also [videos with instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsjmLa16obs).

Answer (score 1):

The plugin Cadinput might be what you are looking for (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/CadInput/). See http://vimeo.com/85052231 for a demonstration.